# Regularity of the distance function to a compact set in an Alexandrov space

Tags: alexandrov-geometry

Let $X$ be a finitely dimensional Alexandrov space with curvature bounded below. For any compact set $K \subset X$, can we find $0<\epsilon_1<\epsilon$ such that the distance function $f=|\cdot K|$ has no critical point in $B_{\epsilon}(K)\backslash B_{\epsilon_1}(K)$?

Comment: I think letting $K$ be a Cantor set in the plane would give a counterexample.